# C# Structs, events and constructor

Tags: c#, events, struct, constructor, initialization

When one wants to have a collection of values, and be notify when that collection changes, the `ObservableCollection` and its `CollectionChanged` event can be used.

However, its `CollectionChanged` event is only fired when modifying the collection itself, not the values it contains. For example, if I have an `ObservableCollection<Image>`, I won't be able to detect when someone accesses the N-th image of the collection and calls a method that modifies it. he same thing is true if I have an `ObservableCollection<Color>`. If I want to be able to monitor when a Color struct contained within the list is assigned, the items themselves must be observable (recursively). A `Color` struct not being observable, I want to encapsulate it into a struct called `ObservableColor`.

The problem is that, the compiler is yelling at me because the event is not being initialized in the constructor. Well first I didn't know an event had to be initialized, and second I have no idea how it is supposed to be initialized.

Below is my code :

```
struct ObservableColor : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Color Value { get; private set; }

    public ObservableColor(Color color)
    {
        Value = color;
    }

    public void Set(Color color)
    {
        Color oldColor = Value;
        Value = color;
        if (Value != oldColor)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make this compile ? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly does the compiler yell?

Comment: Actually it's not exactly the compiler, it's whatever checks the code on the fly. It says "Field ObservableColor.PropertyChanged" must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller" whenever I hover the red underlined constructor name.

Comment: I would highly recommend making this a class rather than a struct in any case - mutable structs are evil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# requires that all fields be explicitly initialized in a value type's constructor. You are getting this error simply because `PropertyChanged` is not assigned anything before the constructor finishes. Fixing this is trivial, just do this:

```
public ObservableColor(Color color)
{
    Value = color;
    PropertyChanged = null;
}
```

That said, you should consider changing your approach. Mutable structs are source of all kind of headaches, unexpected behavior and subtle bugs that can drive you crazy. I'd recommend changing `ObservableColor` to a reference type.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: hahaha this is hilarious, never thought this would be THAT easy^^

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, [mutable structs are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil). So the best way to make this compile is to make this type a `class`:

```
class ObservableColor : INotifyPropertyChanged
{...}
```

If you *really need* this to be a `struct`, then your constructor has to initiaize all fields of the `struct`, even the `event`:

```
struct ObservableColor : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Color Value { get; private set; }

    public ObservableColor(Color color)
    {
        Value = color;
        PropertyChanged = null; // initiailze
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.